Push notifications subscription - what to do after user turn them off on device
I have a question regarding push notifications.
How can I synchronize the state between the device and the backend when a user first allows notifications (a subscription is created and sent to the server), and then disables this subscription from the device settings, and subsequently re-enables it in the device settings?
Unfortunately, after such an action in Chrome, pushManager.getSubscription() returns null instead of the subscription object. How can I manage this so that the user can receive notifications again? If the solution is to create a new subscription on the device and send it to the server, how can I delete the old one, considering that when the permissions are removed on the device, I lose access to the object and cannot identify which subscription should be deleted (assuming the possibility that a user with a given ID has subscriptions on more than one device)?
I have tried many different approaches, including deleting and creating the subscription anew each time the user opens the application (if permission === granted), but when the application was running in the background, the state from the device was not immediately reflected in the application. Only closing and reopening the application would make Notification.permission have the correct state.
My goal is to maintain one subscription per device for users. When the permission is removed and restored from the device settings, the subscription should be deleted from the database via the delete_push_subscription endpoint in my backend application. When the user changes the state through a toggle in the frontend application, the active field of the subscription should change in the same way as the state of the toggle. Backend interface:
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@context": "string",
      "@id": "string",
      "@type": "string",
      "id": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "customerCode": "string",
      "subscription": "string",
      "endpoint": "stringstri",
      "active": "boolean",
      "created": "string"
    }
  ],

At the moment I have no idea how to identify db record when user turns off subscription on the device. Prolly service worker will come handy but I found only 'pushsubscriptionchange' event which is not supported by Android Chrome or Chrome at all.

I have run into a problem I fear you may have encountered and solved. I allow users to subscribe to push notifications using the Web Push API and the way I've designed it is that so far, what makes a user unique is their userId and userAgent.
But we have realized how insufficient that is in terms of making the user subscription on a particular browser & on a particular device unique. Because using just userId and userAgent, if a user wants to unsubscribe from our push notifications, we unsubscribe that user (userId) from all the browsers (userAgent) that have the same userAgent as the one they are currently logged in and unsubscribing from.
I am curious how you navigated this problem - especially if a user is subscribed on Chrome on 2 different devices. How do we just unsubscribe them from the device they are currently using Chrome and unsubscribing on?
Thank you.
